# Zabbix. Не возможно подключиться к базе данных. Не удалось выбрать конфигурацию

Tags: mysql, сеть, debian, zabbix

Мне выдан проект: установка Zabbix сервера на Debian 11 (MySQL, nginx, php7.4, ) и его настройка. Пользоваться Linux можно сказать начал с нуля. На этапе всей установки возникало немалое количество проблем и сложностей. С чувством той самой мартышки дошел наконец таки до веб-интерфейса Zabbix-а и тут столкнулся с очередной ошибкой, которая нигде особо не гуглится и решить ее я все никак не могу.
Суть в следующем - я пытаюсь через веб-интерфейс на странице инсталяции подключиться к своей базе данных, все параметры кроме пароля уже были выставлены по умолчанию. Прописал пароль и попытался продолжить инсталяцию, однако получил ошибку

```
"Не возможно подключиться к базе данных.

Не удалось выбрать конфигурацию."
```

Что делать и как решить (или хотя бы найти решение) эту проблему? Лично я уже не знаю куда следует лезть. Чтобы не было лишних сообщений сразу скажу, что проблема точно не в пароле - с этим я уже помотал себе нервы, к тому же ошибка именно такая как я написал, а НЕ

```
 "Error connecting to database: Access denied for user 'zabbix'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
```

Вход через терминал в саму базу данных производится успешно и без каких-либо проблем. Сервисы zabbix-server, zabbix-agent, mysql работают.

Comment: А вы таблицы в залили начальные данные?

Comment: то, что 'zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-sql-scripts/mysql/server.sql.gz | mysql -uzabbix -p zabbix' ?
@ВладимирКлыков

Comment: Похоже на то :) в бд входите, таблицы есть? таблица config заполнена?

Comment: да, в этом плане все отлично. НО насчет начальных данных, как Вы сказали я не уверен. Дело в том, что когда я пытался их импортировать, то консоль долгое время не выводила никаких сообщения и не сообщала о конце импорта, а ждал я добрые минут 20, после чего просто решил прервать процесс, потому что у  меня уже было что то подобное с обычным запуском zabbix-server.service и после перезахода в консоль zabbix-server прекрасно работал. @ВладимирКлыков

Comment: Насчет config - она и вправду не заполнена :(

Comment: Исходя из вашего ответа - вам нужно очистить бд и повторить импорт данных, только теперь не завершать процедуру до ее окончания.

Comment: не могли бы вы уточнить с командами как именно мне очистить бд, потому что я знаю лишь способ снести всю базу и настраивать все заново (от чего крайне уже устал)@ВладимирКлыков

Comment: Снести схему например drop schema {NAME}

Answer (score 0):

Ребят, ларчик просто открывался... Во первых скрипт от рута запускать, во вторых ошибка в мануале.
zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-sql-scripts/mysql/server.sql.gz | mysql **-uzabbix** -p zabbix  не хватает пробела...